# How to set an applications background the same as the current background?

Tags: android

I am trying to figure out some way to determine the current background on a phone and then set that background as my own in my application to create a seamless transition between my application and the phone. However I haven't been able to find any functions for this at Androids SDK site.

Setting android:theme="@style/Theme.NoBackground" inside my Manifest almost does what I want, but it still has the icons in the background.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Yeah the WallpaperManager was the answer, a little searching revealed this in one of the API Demos for anyone who needs this.

```
final WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);
final Drawable wallpaperDrawable = wallpaperManager.getDrawable();
```

Obviously add the variable wallpaperDrawable to setBackgroundDrawable();

Comment: Don't forget to "accept" answers to questions you post on this site -- just click the big "tick" icon under the most relevant answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should also be able to declare in your manifest that your activity should use the 'wallpaper' theme, like so:

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Wallpaper">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the following code in your program, so that you can overcome your problem:

`activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Wallpaper"`

this will help for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do call this.getWallpaper() in your Activity in prior 2.0.